# How to verify email to continue with registration

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail

I want to make a script in php like given below:

1. When any user registers on my site.
2. A mail will be sent, before continue with the registration to ignore SPAM.
3. User will get an email to verify their email address and continue with their registration **(Same as Stackoverflow)**

How can I achieve this? Please guys help me with any **(STEP BY STEP)** Script / Tutorial / Suggestions / Knowledge.

Comment: What all have you tried so far?  You have a better chance of getting help if you show some of your work and specific errors/issues you are having.  You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Jason all i need is a logic behind it...like how can i generate random link and send it to user mail to continue with registration..getting me?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/

Comment: Please someone answer me...if you can then help me out..while typing this much i think you would also share some links/tutorials/ suggestion to help me out thank you

Comment: Links? You can just search Stack or Google. Surely you can find tutorials? I just copy/paste your question subject into Google as a very simple starting point, which surely with some thought and effort you could have done? https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+verify+email+to+continue+with+registration   No one is going to write your code for you, and we're not here to be a google-proxy service. Take some time to look

Comment: @Rita, please understand that this site is inundated by too-general questions, especially from new users. You're just starting out but some people have seen a lot of it, and forget to be patient. That said, it is true that with a little bit of effort you will find _on this site_ the ingredients you need to move forward. Try it, and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this verification process, you have to set up a PHP site logic which allows you to enter your credentials, then generate a confirmation hash, create a link such as http://www.yoursite.com/activate.php?user=xxx&hash=1a2b3c4d5e and send it along with the email (SMTP). You also set a variable (e.g. bool/tinyint "active") to 0 so the user can't log in until he activated the account. You'll also need kind of a database to store the credentials and hashes and other parameters.

On the other hand you have to build a "activate.php". When the user receives the email, he should have a link which contains username and hash and redirects to the activation site. The site $_GETs the parameters (here named user and hash) and fills them into a textbox each. Then the user has to click on "activate", "active" gets set to 1. Then the user is able to log in.

There are dozens of tutorials on youtube, just search there.

Examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngqeWUIDlnk or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9jiyJ5tRBU

Comment: hmmm..getting it now...cool i m going to try this..can you also share link of tutorial on YouTube please as i cant found it

Comment: That's no problem. If you understand how you can build it, you can easily combine it with (just in case) your existing login system.